# Azure deploying fails

Tags: azure, azure-deployment

I am having troubles with a azure deployment. I am using vs2012 ultimate. After deployment it stops/recycles. Locally in the emulator it works fine.

Its an mvc4 site, from what I have read everyone points to missing dll's not included in deployment.

From what I can tell I think I have selected "Copy to local" on all required dll's

Is there a list anywhere that outline's minimum requirements for an mvc4 application?

My deployments are taking about 20 minutes each time only to find they are failing. I have jumped onto the server and looked in the eventviewer but there is no helpful info.

Can anyone help by letting me know how I can get to the bottom of the problem? is there some magic log someone that will give me something useful.

Comment: Yes. If you are targeting .NET Framework 4.5, make sure that you also use `OSFamily = 3` in your Cloud Project ([Azure Service Configuration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee758710.aspx)).

Comment: Yes already have OSFamily = 3

Comment: Then since you are using VS ULTIMATE I strongly suggest you to try out enabling Intellitrace for your Cloud Project (instructions [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ff683671.aspx)). You can download intellitrace logs even in the role is "recycling" and examine to see what causes the issue. Actually it used to be case when Intellitrace is enabled the role will just crash instead of recycling, for you to be able to examine the exact cause for crashing.

Comment: Some error messages would be helpful. Do you have any start-up scripts or native dll's in your project? What kind of exception message do you see in the portal?

Comment: Thanks astaykov thats got me a little closer. I see an error from the Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime\1.8.0 - Could not load System.Web.Mvc Version 3  - I am not sure what's going on here as its a mvc4 project and I can find any references to mvc3

Answer (score 0):

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30148139/deploy-to-azure-issue-could-not-load-file-or-assembly-system-web-mvc-version][1]

I believe the person had similar issue, and he recommended doing a clean deployment for starters and also possibly looking at the assemblies in the bin before you delete them to verify.

I hope this helps you with your issue.