# Deploy to Azure issue: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.3.0...manifest not match issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure

I'm developing an MVC site and it works fine locally, but when I deploy to my Azure site, I am getting this error:

Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

I should be deploying all of those assemblies.  Since its hosted in Azure, I have limited control over the box, but I thought they would have this assembly on there as well so I'm not sure why this is causing an issue.  Any ideas?

More details:

Server Error in '/' Application.

Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Assembly Load Trace: The following information can be helpful to determine why the assembly 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' could not be loaded.

WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].

Stack Trace:

[FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)]
   marylandgives.mvc.MvcApplication.Application_Start() +0

[HttpException (0x80004005): Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)]
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.EnsureAppStartCalledForIntegratedMode(HttpContext context, HttpApplication app) +9916673
   System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +118
   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +172
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +336
   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr appContext) +296

[HttpException (0x80004005): Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +9930568
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +101
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +254

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.36215

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since I had previously deployed another site on the same location with an older version of the MVC assembly on it, that was causing the conflict.  I ftped into the webroot, wiped everything clean and republished from visual studio.  So this was really just a case of me being lazy and not cleaning off the old site first.

So for anyone else that gets this error, I would advise doing a clean deployment for starters and also possibly looking at the assemblies in the bin before you delete them to verify.

Comment: Also worth noting for anyone in who gets into this situation - rather than ftping into webroot you can simply check a setting when publishing to remove files at the destination first - this should achieve the same result (assuming you publish from visual studio!)

Comment: @Michael Hudson That solved the problem I was facing. Much simpler than ftping in.

Answer (score 1):

This basically happenes when .NET asslembly loader tries to load an assembly other than what is specified in project file. Try to update the nuget package for `System.Web.Mvc` in
this and all **referenced** projects and make sure that your project points to the correct assembly version.

Comment: Thanks Arin.  I understand it's trying to load the wrong assembly.  What I wasn't sure of was why because it works locally, so my nuget packages are on the right version.  I think the problem was because I had deployed another site to the same location previously and it was using an older version of MVC, so I think I forgot to wipe those assets off before deploying the new site and my new site is getting confused with the older mvc dll there.  I'll keep investigating tonight and post the results soon.

Comment: Check the compiler warnings too, most of the times you can easily find out what goes wrong by checking compiler warnings.

Comment: Thanks Arin.  This wasn't a compile time issue though because it worked fine locally.  My hunch was correct that since I had previously deployed another site on the same location with an older version of the MVC assembly on it, that was causing the conflict.  I ftped into the webroot, wiped everything clean and republished from visual studio.